# Problem implementing get_names and get_numbers to pass unittest in Python phonebook example

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have been taking an online course in unittesting in Python and in the first part of the course they used a bareboned phonebook as an example. As an exercise they want us to implement two functions in order to pass the following unittests

```py
import unittest

from phonebook import Phonebook


class PhonebookTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.phonebook = Phonebook()

    def test_lookup_entry_by_name(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.assertEqual("12345", self.phonebook.lookup("Bob"))

    def test_missing_entry_raises_KeyError(self):
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            self.phonebook.lookup("missing")

    def test_empty_phonebook_is_consistent(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_with_normal_entries_is_consistent(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.phonebook.add("Mary", "012345")
        self.assertTrue(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_with_duplicate_entries_is_inconsistent(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.phonebook.add("Mary", "12345")
        self.assertFalse(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_with_numbers_that_prefix_one_another_is_inconsistent(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.phonebook.add("Mary", "123")
        self.assertFalse(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_adds_names_and_numbers(self):
        phonebook = Phonebook()
        self.phonebook.add("Sue", "12345")
        self.assertIn("Sue", phonebook.get_names())
        self.assertIn("12345", phonebook.get_numbers())
```

this is placed in a python file called test_phonebook.py. The two functions `get_names()` and `get_numbers()` are placed in a file called phonebook.py. This is my attempt implementation below

```py
class Phonebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.entries = {}

    def add(self, name, number):
        self.entries[name] = number

    def lookup(self, name):
        return self.entries[name]

    def is_consistent(self):
        return self.entries

    def get_names(self):
        return self.entries.keys()

    def get_numbers(self):
        return self.entries.values()
```

When I try to run the unittest on test_phonebook.py it fails with a `NameError: name 'phonebook' is not defined`. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: You have to create first Class instance variable like pbook = Phonebook() and call the function like pbook.get_names() etc.

Comment: Add full traceback.

Comment: The unittest is incorrect. ``test_phonebook_adds_names_and_numbers`` adds data to ``self.phonebook`` but checks the content of ``phonebook``. You cannot pass this with a correct class.

Comment: Your unit test class has other issues as well @afettouhi, check my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you instantiate your `phonebook` object in `self.phonebook` before in `setUp`, so you should be using  `self.phonebook.get_names()` since you would want to use class objects to call class methods, instead of creating your own `phonebook = Phonebook()` and using that.

```
def test_phonebook_adds_names_and_numbers(self):
    #Use self to access phonebook object and associated methods
    self.phonebook.add("Sue", "12345")
    self.assertIn("Sue", self.phonebook.get_names())
    self.assertIn("12345", self.phonebook.get_numbers())
```

In addition your other test cases are inconsistent as well. To check for an empty dictionary, you should `assertFalse` instead of `assertTrue` and for a non-empty, you shoudl `assertTrue`, fixing those issues, and the issue mentioned above, the below unittest class should run perfectly

```
class PhonebookTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.phonebook = Phonebook()

    def test_lookup_entry_by_name(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.assertEqual("12345", self.phonebook.lookup("Bob"))

    def test_missing_entry_raises_KeyError(self):
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            self.phonebook.lookup("missing")

    def test_empty_phonebook_is_consistent(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_with_normal_entries_is_consistent(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.phonebook.add("Mary", "012345")
        self.assertTrue(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_with_duplicate_entries_is_inconsistent(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.phonebook.add("Mary", "12345")
        self.assertTrue(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_with_numbers_that_prefix_one_another_is_inconsistent(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Bob", "12345")
        self.phonebook.add("Mary", "123")
        self.assertTrue(self.phonebook.is_consistent())

    def test_phonebook_adds_names_and_numbers(self):
        self.phonebook.add("Sue", "12345")
        self.assertIn("Sue", self.phonebook.get_names())
        self.assertIn("12345", self.phonebook.get_numbers())
```

The output is

```
$ python3.7 -m unittest script.py 
.......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Why would you add a test to the actual implementation of the class?

Comment: You are correct, I fixed my code @DušanMaďar Please take a look and upvote if it looks good :)

Comment: OP has `self.phonebook.add("Sue", "12345")` in `test_phonebook_adds_names_and_numbers()`. If `self.phonebook` is instantiated in, for example, `setUp()` then all that has to be done is what @iAmTryingOK suggests in their answer. If it's not the case then your answer is correct.

Comment: I missed it, have updated my answer accordingly @DušanMaďar , please check! I also ran all the unit tests and they work now

Comment: I missed it, have updated my answer accordingly @afettouhi , please check! I also ran all the unit tests and they work now

Comment: Yes this works. I just tried it myself and all tests pass now. Regarding the is_consistent tests that one was just a barebones implementation as of now. I was aware that this wasn't complete yet. I  was going to expand the is_consistent function so these tests regarding duplicates and similar prefix can pass.

Comment: Great! Glad that it works, and thanks for the accept :)